# Рассчитывает ли Postgres сходство запросов для выбора оптимального плана?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Рассчитывает ли Postgres внутри себя сходство запросов для выбора оптимального плана или нет?

Если считает то как он определяет расстояние между двумя запросами?
Вопрос родился после прочтения этот статьи

http://www2.cs.uh.edu/~ordonez/pdfwww/p-2008-HPDM-sqldist.pdf

Comment: Нет, не рассчитывает. Это не требуется. План выполнения строится исходя из структуры БД и статистики собранной по данным.

Answer (score 2):

`Задача планировщика/оптимизатора` — построить наилучший план выполнения. Определённый SQL-запрос (а значит, и дерево запроса) на самом деле можно выполнить самыми разными способами, при этом получая одни и те же результаты. Если это не требует больших вычислений, оптимизатор запросов будет перебирать все возможные варианты планов, чтобы в итоге выбрать тот, который должен выполниться быстрее остальных.

[Планировщик/оптимизатор](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/enterprise/9.6/planner-optimizer)

[Оптимизация производительности](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/performance-tips)

Пример:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
  a INTEGER,
  b INTEGER,
  c INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table_1
  SELECT i, i + 10, i + 100
  FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;


SELECT * FROM table_1;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_1;

SELECT a, b, c FROM table_1;
EXPLAIN SELECT a, b, c FROM table_1; --предполагаемый план выполнения
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b, c FROM table_1; --реальный план выполнения

SELECT a, b FROM table_1;
EXPLAIN SELECT a, b FROM table_1;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b FROM table_1;

SELECT a, b FROM table_1 WHERE c > 1000;
EXPLAIN SELECT a, b FROM table_1 WHERE c > 1000;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b FROM table_1 WHERE c > 1000;
```

[Оптимизация запросов. Основы EXPLAIN в PostgreSQL](https://habr.com/ru/post/203320/)

Comment: Вопрос не об этом. Интересует сравнивает ли Postgres как-то запросы между собой на схожесть или нет и если сравнивает то как?

Comment: @Иван Гладуш, Вы можете запрос написать 2 или 3 способами, а план выполнения в них может быть одинаков, думаю я ответил на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: все верно, запрос можно написать 2 или 3 или больше способами. Меня интересует возможность сравнивать два запроса на равенство и различия без планировщика. Я хотел узнать сделана ли такая функция в постгрес и если да, то как.  Сравнение планов это круто, но их нужно еще построить, что достаточно сложная операция при большом кол-ве джоинов. Если же бд сможет быстро сказать похожи два запроса или нет, то можно сделать ряд оптимизаций по времени построению плана

Comment: Чтобы СУБД поняла, похожи ли запросы, она должна построить их планы, так понятнее?

Comment: @gbg  так понятнее, но это точно? может можно как-то из квери понять они одинаковы или нет?

Comment: @Иван Гладуш, чтобы произвести сравнение двух запросов нужно построить планы выполнение, а потом принимать какое то решение

Comment: @Yaroslav вы говорите мне про планы запроса. Хорошо, а как сравнить на сколько похожи 2 плана запроса. Например, если первый запрос select a,b,c from table_1, то он похож на запрос select a,b from table_1, но менее похож на запрос select a,b from table_1 where c>10. Если у вас знания как сравнить на сколько похожи 2 плана запросов, как посчитать расстояние между двумя планами запросов?

Comment: @Иван Гладуш, дополнил ответ.